# What 70’s short story has a species go extinct every day, ending with a microscopic one, then humans?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story (I believe it was in an anthology dating from the 1970's) where a species goes extinct every day.

It concludes with some microscopic or very tiny species dying out, followed by humans (who were dependent on that life form for their own existence).

Comment: Except for the last two species, you might be confusing short stories with real life.

Comment: Does the story take place in 2430 A.D.?

Answer (score 4):

["And Us, Too, I Guess"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?71145) by George Alec Effinger (1973). The start of it can be read on  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=nBAeAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT16&ots=5VFt1aXPYk&dq=george%20alec%20effinger%20%22and%20us%20too%2C%20I%20guess%22&pg=PT16#v=onepage&q=george%20alec%20effinger%20%22and%20us%20too,%20I%20guess%22&f=false) in the *Irrational Numbers* collection:

> "I had two broods in the step tanks, plus the breeding stock. I had over a hundred mollies in the big tank. Not a single one of them's still alive."